# How does moving a unix domain socket enable socat to monitor traffic?

Tags: socket, socat

`socat` can be used to monitor traffic across a Unix domain socket:

```
sudo mv /path/to/sock /path/to/sock.original
sudo socat -t100 -x -v UNIX-LISTEN:/path/to/sock,mode=777,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/path/to/sock.original
```

I don't quite understand how this mechanism works, hoping someone could explain it a little. In particular, how does moving the socket file work if a process is already listening on it? Also, after the move:
neither `lsof /path/to/sock` nor `/path/to/sock.original` return any results.

Answer (score 11):

Those commands have to be run when the server you want to monitor is currently listening on `/path/to/sock`. Then, if you rename `/path/to/sock`, the server won't be affected.

The `socat` command inserts a man-in-the-middle. It listens on `/path/to/socks` and forwards all the traffic by the clients to `/path/to/socks.original` (and logs it in the process with `-v`).

That only works for *stream* types of sockets (use `UNIX-RECVFROM`/`UNIX-RECV` for *datagram* sockets) and only if the clients just to `read/write/send/recv` on those sockets, not `sendmsg()` with ancillary data and other fancy things.

`lsof` will only report the listening processes (`socat` and the server for the listening and accepted sockets). It's generally not possible to link a *connected* socket on the client to the path of the socket.

If you do that *before* starting the server, then that won't work as the server will try to *listen* on `/path/to/socks` and fail as `socat` is already listening on that. Or you need to tell the server to listen on `/path/to/sock.original` instead.